# Eclipse puts maven runtime scoped dependencies on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have `apache commons lang` dependency in `runtime` scope. The goal was to have it in `runtime` scope so that it is not available to anyone and they should be using `apache commons lang3` which is available in `compile` time scope. However, `apache commons lang` is available in eclipse classpath and I am able to use that in eclipse and write my code, which defeats the purpose of having it in `runtime` scope. How should I tell eclipse to not to put it on classpath via `Maven Dependencies` ?

Comment: What you have described sounds like `provided` and not `runtime`.

Comment: Well, `provided` will be provided by the container. I don't have any sort of container providing this.. I only have to provide this, thus runtime

Comment: Runtime dependency means, that it's needed at runtime, so it instructs maven to add it to the runtime classpath (so it gets as transitive dependency to any application, that uses it). So what you see is correct. I probably do not understand the purpose of your desired setup. If You want the code to get compiled with `apache-commons-lang3` and then run it with `apache-commons-lang`, what should be the benefit? If you code in fact doesn't depend on that library, then don't add it at all.

Comment: Well, `apache-commons-lang` is coming down as a transitive dependency from another dependency. I don't have added it explicitly and for some known reason, I cannot exclude it. So, in dependency management, I am overriding it's scope to runtime and making unavailable at compile time, which works if I try to compile the project via command line maven but not in eclipse. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: What is the known reason that you cannot exclude the transitive dependency?

Comment: The project which it is coming from is not in my control and it is being used by some other team as well. I can not just exclude lang, they might be using it but I am not.

Comment: Please show a sample pom.xml which will describe your situation better.